# How to post code to Google Code?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, svn, tortoisesvn, google-code

I am new to SVN, subversion, etc. I have a C# application in MS Visual Studion 2008 that I would like to share on Google Code.

I have been looking around for some info on how to do that without any luck. I have now installed TortoiseSVN. When I right-click and choose Export or Import I get the following error messages:

```
"Server sent unexpected return value (405 Method Not Allowed) in response to"
"OPTIONS request for 'http://code.google.com/p/atm/source/browse/%23svn/trunk'"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe these might work for you. Screenshots included.

http://devwatch.wordpress.com/2008/10/25/how-to-access-google-code-svn/

http://mzaher.wordpress.com/2009/03/02/how-to-use-svn-with-google-code/

Comment: @darktangent Thanks, I hope you enjoy SO.